# wrapp twitter bootstrap in a custom wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I try to use bootstrap in my custom wordpress Plugin but seems to broke all admin area with the following

```
class MyPlugin{
 public function iniAdmin(){
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'register_collections_menu_page'));
        add_action( 'admin_init', array($this,'style_bootstrap' ));
    }
    public function style_bootstrap(){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.9.1', true); // we need the jquery library for bootsrap js to function
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true); // all the bootstrap javascript goodness
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    }

}

$collections_settings = new MyPlugin();
if (is_admin()){
    $collections_settings->iniAdmin();
}
```

How to wrap in a propper way bootstrap style in a wordpress plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long search I found a really good tutorial on how to recompile twitter-bootstrap to use in Wordpress admin. You can [find it here](http://hereswhatidid.com/2014/02/use-bootstrap-3-styles-within-the-wordpress-admin/).

**Using Bootstrap 3**

Create a new `.less` on the same directory where your `bootstrap.css` is (for example `wordpress-bootstrap.less`) and wrap the following

```
.bootstrap-wrapper {
    @import (less) url( 'bootstrap.css' );
}
```

... after all you have to recompile your css (I used `winless`) and you get `wordpress-bootstrap.css` wrapped inside `.bootstrap-wrapper`.

Then, you're ready to go!

Comment: And to avoid conflicts with the javascript is any extra step required?

Comment: Javascript conflicts you have to try to fix on wordpress side. Wrapping your JS like `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(#somefunction) ...
});`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! I'm trying this method with Bootstrap 4, and it seems to work very well too.