# Include Bootstrap in a Wordpress plugin : the right way?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to include Bootstrap in my Wordpress plugin (to use CSS+JS features on the front end). The problem is not "how to include it", but how to include it **the right way**.

I mean :

- If other plugin's developers included Bootstrap, every Bootstrap files will be loaded twice (or more). Bad for perf, and can generate conflicts.
- What if the user is using an old version of Bootstrap for a theme or a plugin?

Is there any way to include Bootstrap the right way? This answer looks pretty interesting : [wrapp twitter bootstrap in a custom wordpress plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858529/wrapp-twitter-bootstrap-in-a-custom-wordpress-plugin) but it's just a part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call `wp_enqueue_style()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` as per the [WordPress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) docs, as you would in general use theme **functions.php**